# Samsung Series 5 overheating

Tags: 12.04, samsung, overheating

I bought a Samsung Series 5 Ultra 2 weeks ago and installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am experiencing problems with overheating. When streaming, watching a movie or when having several programms/actions going on at the same time the CPU temperature rises to 95 degrees and the computer freezes. This happens sometimes when the computer is on battery and always when it is recharging. When I am using the computer on battery the CPU temperature is floating from around 75-95 degrees depending what it's doing. When the battery is recharging the CPU temperature is ranging from 88-95 degrees no matter what tasks it performs.

Have anyone experienced this and how may the problem be solved?

Best regards

Comment: Check whether problem from the battery by removing the battery and giving direct power supply.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider installing jupiter

You can select power modes with it, it's very easy to control, just set it to power on command, you wont notice that your laptop is on, until you start using heavy apps. Plus it will stay way cooler.

open terminal and do this:

> add the repository
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
> ```
>
> update
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> install jupiter
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install jupiter
> ```
>
> and to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook,
>   install this asswell
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
> ```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a script to throttle your CPU frequency based on temperature. You set a max temperature, and if your system goes over that temperature it slows down your CPU(s).

http://seperohacker.blogspot.com/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Until today I had the same problem. It seems instel_pstate which regulates thermal issues on newer intels is no longer enabled by default. Assuming you have intel cpus you might be suffering the same problem.

I solved it by installing enabling pstate & installing thermald.

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/prevent-your-laptop-from-overheating.html

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...