# Does booting Ubuntu in Samsung laptop brick them? How do I know without taking risk of my laptops

Tags: boot, samsung

I've got 2 Samsung laptops (Samsung NP550P5C-S01IN & Samsung NP350V5C-S06IN)

I've read it recently that booting Linux in Samsung laptops [bricked them permanently](http://m.tech2.com/news/software/booting-linux-bricks-some-samsung-windows-8-laptops/733642).

I wish to install Ubuntu on both of these but I want to know if I can install Ubuntu in any one of them without bricking them permanently. Is there any way through which I can verify if these can boot Ubuntu safely since both of them have that **Secure BOOT** thing on them.

Please help.

Comment: I read in some article, about some code in windows can also brick. Because it is caused by samsung BIOS. Best advice stay out of it. If you are determined, flash latest firmware from Samsung. turn off secure boot & if possible switch to legacy (need windows re installation). But lets wait for a good answer, who has a good knowledge on it.

Comment: Did you try it? What were your results?

Comment: I have a NP700something. Disabled UEFI mode and update to last bios before wiping out windows7; it works, only thing it needs "radeon.dpm=1" in boot parameters (or nomodeswitch) to work, otherwise it will overheat. http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Comment: What is the bottom line? Is it impossible to install Ubuntu on a Samsung NP350V5C in a separate partition alongside of the pre-installed Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

That article is talking about Windows 8 laptops, which neither of your laptops are.

Also, neither of your laptops are listed among the models containing the bug.

From the article, I don't see any reason to assume the bug would affect your laptops.

Answer (score 2):

**Installation of Linux Causing Samsung Laptop To Brick**

This bug only applies to some Laptop Models that use UEFI and are designed for Windows 8.

If you have a Samsung Laptop that came with Windows 8 pre-installed then I would be think very carefully before attempting to install any other OS.  If your computer did not come with Windows 8 and uses BIOS instead of UEFI.  It should be fine to install Ubuntu.

[source](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/02/booting-linux-instead-of-windows-8-bricks-some-samsung-laptops/) there is more [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2026807/booting-linux-via-uefi-can-brick-some-samsung-laptops.html) and [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2027819/not-just-linux-windows-can-brick-samsung-laptops-too.html)