# Where can I download Ubuntu for intel?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I can't find an Ubuntu installer to format the PC and install it.

Answer (score 2):

You can download Ubuntu from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

My personal choice would be 12.04 as its supported for longer (April 2017) but if you want the latest features download 12.10.  The only other choice is 32-bit or 64-bit.  It's up to you which you choose to download.

The 32-bit version contains **i386** in the name and 64-bit version contains **amd64** do not be put off by this both will work with either amd or intel processors.

If you have a new PC that came with Windows 8 installed take a look at [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system) otherwise you have a choice between a dual boot or Wubi install both are explained in this question [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)

Caution if you have a Samsung Laptop that came with Windows 8 pre-installed [read this first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269906/does-booting-ubuntu-in-samsung-laptop-brick-them-how-do-i-know-without-taking-r/269941#269941) otherwise you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Intel uses the same instructions as AMD.
You can find in: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Why the *alternative downloads* link?

Comment: You right, i thought that he cant install the main version