# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on samsung seties 5

Tags: samsung

how to install Ubuntu 13.04 using usb on my Samsung Series 5  laptop (windows 8)?

i don't want to delete windows and i want to use both of them.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported

Comment: Also take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/269906/107450) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/270036/107450).  There was an issue with "bricking" Samsung laptops. I don't know if it has been fixed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best thing about Ubuntu is that it can be installed alongside the existing operating system.

Ubuntu gives you an option of either replacing the existing operation system, or installing it alongside the existing operating system **(dual-booting)**.

To create a bootable usb from windows, follow this procedure :

> First, download an image of Ubuntu from [The Ubuntu Releases Source](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/)
>   ...choose the option that suits your machine (32 bit or 64 bit versions), then download a software called [Rufus Bootable Disk Writer](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)
>    which enables you to create bootable USB drives. When you have these two...plug in your flash drive...and run the ***rufus*** executable from your desktop. Then use rufus to create a bootable flash, specifying the Ubuntu Image file you would've downloaded as the operation system you want to use.
>   Make sure that you choose the "ntfs" option during creation of your bootable usb. The start the creation process.
>   After its done, eject your flash disk and re-plug it onto your samsung machine.
>   Run the executable in the flash,(***wubi.exe***) and then it should give an option of *trying and installing ubuntu*. It should prompt you for a restart, and let it restart your machine.

During restart,your machine will prompt you to press any key to boot from Usb drive.
The ubuntu installation menu will come up after a few seconds. Choose the full installation option, and after a few steps, there will come up a dialogue that will ask you whether you want to **install ubuntu alongside windows** or replace it....Please carefully choose the "install alongside.." option...and you are done :)