# Much lower battery life on Ubuntu and laptop heating up badly

Tags: 12.10, drivers, power-management, battery

I have the following config laptop:

```
System model: HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC
Processor: AMD A8-4500 APU with Radeon HD Graphics (Quadcore 1.9Ghz)
Memory: 6Gb RAM
Graphics:AMD Radeon HD 7640G+7600M Dual Graphics
```

I usually get a battery run time of 2.5 hours and more in windows, but when I run Ubuntu, it gives me less than 40 mins and it heats up very badly. Can someone please tell me what to do to get a better battery life and processing power. It would be helpful if some one could give me specific instructions.

Comment: I assume both the gpu are on. You need to install ATI driver.

Comment: how to install it?

Comment: i was reading about installing catalyst in ubuntu but there seems to be some problem with the new kernel

Comment: A quick fix would be to disable the dedicated graphics in the BIOS if possible. At the very least this would let you ensure the problem is the GPU.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: Another interesting post is http://askubuntu.com/questions/207733/why-does-my-laptop-with-amd-radeon-hd-76xx-graphics-get-overheated-when-using-ub

Answer (score 1):

I use Indicator-cpu , It helped me to some extent... I use the ondemand mode

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:artfwo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I tried this and was successful. I am using a Laptop with similar configurations.

- Download the latest driver using this link: 
  http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.zip
- Extract it, and open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
- `cd` to the directory in which the zip file is extracted.
- Run the following command:

  ```
  sudo sh amd-catalyst-13.4-linux-x86.x86_64.run
  ```

Afterwards a new window appears, select the top radio button; and click on bottom right button and continue it. After finishing the installation, click the bottom button.

- Goto Catalyst control center
- Goto Switchable graphics
- Select Power saving GPU.
- Click apply

Answer (score 0):

I also had overheating issues with my HP g6 laptop.
I have installed AMD Catalyst & Indicator-cpu.

I also installed TLP power management following

http://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-13-10/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw 
sudo tlp start
```

Dont know which one did the trick but now my laptop is very much cool

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 14.04+ there is also `thermald` -- see my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/601652/161463) for details.