# ubuntu 13.10 radeon.dpm=1

Tags: radeon, gpu

Does radeon power management work out of the box on ubuntu 13.10 by putting radon.dpm=1 on the kernel boot parameters or do I need also to update the firmware files ?

Answer (score 0):

I asume that you might have to update the firmware as I have tried it without updating the firmware and it does not work for me out of the box with radeon.dpm=1 as boot parameter. I have the Radeon HD 4225 card and my notebook heats up like mad. Powertop shows a consumption of 20 Watts in idle. I didn't update the firmeware as I could not find appropriate files.

Comment: Maybe my answer http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395 could help. I does not really work in automatic mode, but at least I can cool it down manually.