# Black screen after boot with AMD Radeon graphic card enabled

Tags: boot, kubuntu, radeon

I have a problem with booting Kubuntu 13.10 on a lenovo G510 notebook with this specs:

-CPU: Intel core i5 4200M
-Graphic card: Intel Graphics HD 4600 + AMD Radeon HD 8570m
-S.O.: Windows 8.1/Kubuntu 13.10

When I try to boot Kubuntu with the Radeon enabled, it results in a black screen, instead if I disable it from the BIOS and use only UMA Graphics it works perfectly. So the problem is the Radeon, but I can't keep it turned off all the time, it'd be a waste! Maybe it's because I haven't installed the drivers for the Radeon, but I can't install them while the radeon is disabled.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can install the drivers even without the card enabled. 
If you want to go with open source drivers, the correct packages is xserver-xorg-video-radeon (but you should have it installed by default).

I had a lot of problems with my Intel + Radeon combo (it's a 7400m here, so maybe it doesn't apply to you). I put some consideration here: https://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Basically, to go with the open-source drivers you just make sure you have the aforementioned package installed and make sure you **do not** have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file. (If you have, backup it and try to remove it).

To go with the proprietary AMD drivers you can simply install them with

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

and then reboot.

Be prepared to having to rescue the system if they do not work by entering again in recovery mode and uninstalling them --- remember to remove the `xorg.conf` file in this case; uninstalling the `fglrx` packages will not automatically remove it, and if present the open source drivers will not work.

Useful question/answers: [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)

Comment: Wow man thanks a lot. I installed proprietary amd drivers, i removed that xorg.conf, reboot, and bum! It works perfectly even with the radeon enabled. I'm really greatful :)

Answer (score 0):

I use Lenovo G710 laptop. In the end it has proven to boot Ubuntu 13.10 properly, the only problem being that is does so with the screen turned off. If the problem is indeed the same as mine, then I believe G510 has analogous keyboard to G710, so you can turn the screen on simply using (Fn+)F9 or (Fn+)F12 keys.

Comment: lol I wished it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have kubuntu 13.10 installed on my desktop, cpu Q8400 with Radeon HD5800 card. I have got the fglrx installed from the package manager which is ATI driver packaging version 13.10 since I wasn't able to get the latest 13.12 version downloaded from ATI website to work on kubuntu 13.10 (failed to compiled properly due to some software packages missing).My graphic card has both DVI (which I use a DVI to VGA converter) and a HDMI port.

My problem is same as yours, it give me a blank screen if I use the HDMI port to connect to my monitor.

However, I found that if I connect to another monitor with the DVI port at the same time, all with be fine. Both the monitors will show cloned dual images.

This blank screen problem will persist even if I go to the ATI catalyst configuration and disabled the DVI monitor; as long as the DVI port is plugged in (even if it is disabled in the ATI config) the HDMI monitor will show desktop screen without problem. But when I removed the DVI port connection, the HDMI monitor will show a blank screen.

Btw, if I purge the fglrx driver and used the default free ubuntu graphic driver this problem goes away. So, the graphic card has no problem. The problem lies with the ATI Radeon proprietary driver. However, I need the fglrx driver for the HDMI audio and the flash player to work properly.

Thus, now I am using my desktop by connecting to both monitors but with the second monitor(DVI) power off and disabled at the ATI config . Strange but it works for me. hahaha

Hope this help you.