# What version of Ubuntu support switchable graphics?

Tags: hybrid-graphics

I have an HP with Inter and ATI and i want to have Ubuntu on my notebook. I have installed the version 12.04 and I didn´t found any driver for my graphic card :( what is the version that i need to install to have my PC wotking with full hardware? Thanks :D

Comment: How did you come at this conclusion?

Comment: I viewed "this PC" in settings and there was Intel graphic card. Now it says ATI Radeon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 10.10 and newer.

All of your questions are in this quote ([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)):

> **How to switch the GPU**
>
> The kernel shipped in Ubuntu 10.10 supports hybrid graphics by means of the vga_switcheroo flag. See vga_switcheroo below.
>
> **Enabling vga_switcheroo**
>
> vga_switcheroo is the kernel mechanism that allows you to switch
>   between GPUs if your machine has a hardware mux. Note that this method
>   is not supported by all machines and only works if you are using the
>   opensource driver (nouveau, radeon) and not the proprietary ones
>   (nvidia, fglrx).
>
> To check whether your kernel is compiled with the proper option you
>   can examine the file config-2.6.nn-mm-generic in the /boot directory:
>
> ```
> grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-*
> ```
>
> The vga_switcheroo mechanism will only be active when the kernel is
>   booted with either the `modeset=1` kernel option, and/or the
>   `nomodeset` option being absent.
>
> To test if vga_switcheroo is enabled, look for the switch file:
>
> ```
> ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
> ```

Comment: I have a Chronos 7 working with opensource drivers in 13.10  (muxless). See http://askubuntu.com/a/393727/16395 and http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Comment: This driver installs automaticaly when i install Ubuntu? (I am very new to Linux)

Comment: @ihavenokia yes the one in my quote is the normal one that gets installed by default but Ubuntu also allows you to easily switch (it is 1 selection, enter a password and 1 ok button  to do so).