# Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit running on low graphics mode on windows 8?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, graphics, 64-bit

I have tried installing ubuntu 14.04 64-bit on windows 8 , the installation completed without any error but after installation completed it shows me a message that System is running in low graphics mode, on other hand i have successfully installed ubuntu 14.04 32-bit on same system.

Now I want to reinstall 64-bit ubuntu , what should i do to overcome that error message.

I know this question is duplicate but i did not found any solution yet thats why i am re-posting this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean two systems on the same computer? Update your video driver for Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Comment: yes two system on same computer , i have a pre installed windows 8 , above which i have tried ubuntu 14.04 62 bit but failed due to this error ,  can u please tell me how to update the driver ? or how to check status of my driver

Comment: Did you try these links?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

http://askubuntu.com/questions/393694/black-screen-after-boot-with-amd-radeon-graphic-card-enabled

What is your videocard model?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Zacharee1 The thing is I couldn't leave a comment because I hadn't reached 50 points of reputation, though I wanted to :(

Comment: It's still against the rules to do so.

Comment: can i update the driver after installation by running ubuntu in live session mode via bootable USB device will it work ,? or do i need to follow some other step

Comment: I have removed Windows and installed ubuntu 14.04  from fresh and also followed all the steps given in above link,  but still the problem persist , can somebody help me on this