# how to install RADEON Open Source and Ati Catalyst (fglrx) together?

Tags: drivers, ati, video, radeon, fglrx

-ubuntu 13.10-
i have two ATI video cards. Onboard RS690 (x1200) and PCIe R9-290
RS690 only works with radeon open source since Amd doesnt support it anymore
R9 only works with new ati drivers (i try with catalyst 13.12)

```
lspci | grep VGA  
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 [Radeon X1200]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290]
```

each card works well individually in a fresh installation
all attempts for work together were disastrous, so the question is:

how to install RADEON Open Source and Ati Catalyst (fglrx) together ??

Comment: Given that AMD has decided not to support such a old-new mixed configuration, I fear that your only options is to hope that the open-source drivers could manage the two cards. Not sure if it's possible...

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say, but you can't basically. The only thing I could imagine is if you have vt-d to use one in a xen vm.

Answer (score 0):

The onboard graphics doesn't work when you are using your R9 290:

Use the following command for hybrid graphics:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

PS: never use open drivers because they are very broken (eg: on laptops they overheat them greatly)

Comment: Not more often broken than the proprietary drivers. In my laptop fglrx and fglrx-updates both don't work. And yes, open drivers do overheat, but I could fix them (at least here). Moreover, if noone use open source drivers, we will never have them working reliably. See http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395