# laptop overheating also after installing latest kernel

Tags: hp, radeon, overheating

I got HP g6 laptop with i3 processor, AMD radeon 7450M dedicated GPU. I got ubuntu 13.10 installed. It is overheating too much. I tried changing to latest kernel 3.12.x and also edited grub file

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

Still my laptop is overheating.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Try to see if this one helps: http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Answer (score 0):

If you have not removed the older kernel versions then you can remove newly installed kernel and then try using older kernels!
See if your laptop still overheats!

Comment: i didn't remove older kernel, directly installed new one. But i was also having overheating problems with old kernel.

Comment: Well HP laptops have a problem of overheating..even I have a HP laptop which gets overheated after 1hr or so..