# Laptop shuts down immediately upon starting game from Steam

Tags: nvidia, laptop, games, shutdown, steam

I have just reformatted Ubuntu, and have updated the drivers.

Games from Steam crash and the computer shuts down immediately upon loading or starting the game. This happens both on Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

I have 6GB RAM
GT 630M graphics card
Core i5 -2450m 2.5GHz CPU  (Acer V3 771G 6601)

Games like L4D2 and TF2 shut down the computer instantly. Is it a hardware malfunction? According to the specs it can handle those games easily. Help please!

Comment: Seems a case of overheating of the GPU, had similar on AMD.

Comment: I am going to try Memtest and report back, also I might have to open up laptop and clean it, this might take time. Are there any other necessary drivers to update ?  I have also tried Furmark on Windows 7, it shuts down the laptop immediately as well .

Comment: @Rmano I recommend posting an answer about that. (It wouldn't have to be a long answer.)

Comment: I forgot to add the link: http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395