# Overheating Laptop when Ubuntu is running?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, overheating

I am currently using HP dual boot windows 8 with Ubuntu 12.04. No problem with windows 8 but when I switch it in to Ubuntu, it getting heat so much. Even i cant work for much period of time it will thermal shutdown the machine. Please tell me a solution but I need Ubuntu can not replace with Mint or anything else.

My Laptop details : **HP 1000 Notebook , Core i3 , 4GB RAM , AMD Radeon HD 6400M Series VGA**

Comment: Usually I see overheating problems but from Windows. I would suggest checking your graphics drivers simply because they might be running with the wrong driver active, this can cause a heat up.

Something else I've encountered that you might wish to check for is that you don't have tracker installed. Tracker can not only make your computer run hot, but it can also make it very slow.

Comment: See if this can help: http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395 (other answers in the same questions, too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for the amd drivers. if the graphics card drivers are not installed on the laptop, you will definitely find a lot of graphics card overheating. check whether the graphics card is identified in ubuntu and whether the driver is installed or not. if the amd driver is already installed, try changing to another driver

Answer (score 0):

I never had a problem overheating because of ubuntu, may your drivers misbehaved or not proper installation cause this problem. Check every drivers installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to find out if a process has a high CPU usage (using 'System Monitor'). This could produce lots of heat.

If the heat is produced by your CPU you could try to install 'indicator-cpufreq' and then you could set it to 'powersave'. This would possibly make your computer a bit slower, but should make it less hot.

Answer (score 0):

It might be your graphics card. You can try running the command (as root)

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

It isn't the best permanent solution because it turns your AMD gpu off, but it should help with the heat if that's the source. You can read more about vga_switcheroo here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

Answer (score 0):

You are right...! Problem was with VGA Drivers. Just needed to install relevant drivers to the machine. But first you should identify your VGA card properly. Thanks for every one who gave help.