# Overheating - ATI HD6470M, Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ati, overheating, hybrid-graphics

I'm trying Linux for the first time ever and experiencing a lot of overheating. In about 45min after I turn on my laptop I get to temps like 90ºC. I googled it and saw a lot of people with the same problem who identified its source as being the GPU.

Whenever I install the fglrx driver and reboot the system, I get a plain black screen with a black "X" as the mouse cursor (which forces me to reinstall Ubuntu).
Adding "radeon.dpm=1" to the grub file and keeping the open-source driver didn't work too. I've also tried some methods to switch between Intel HD and AMD, but couldn't get those to work either.

Can anyone help? Anything that keeps my laptop from melting will suit, and I don't intend to play games or use my GPU heavily in any way.

Comment: Just adding `radeon.dpm=1` and nothing more does not help, you have to tune the power settings. Look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Comment: By the way, you do not need to reinstall linux if the graphic drivers are failing: login with a virtual terminal, or in recovery mode, and follow http://askubuntu.com/a/68312/16395