# AMD graphics power management support in Trusty Tahr's kernel

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics, 14.04

I upgraded to 14.04 just today and since I'm now using kernel v3.13 and according to [This link](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.13#head-f95c198f6fdc7defe36f470dc8369cf0e16898df), I should now be having **power management enabled by default**

How can I confirm that ?

My machine: **Dell Inspiron SE 7520**

My GPU (Discrete\Independent graphics card): **AMD Radeon HD 7730m**

My APU (Graphics card integrated into the processor): **Intel® Ivybridge Mobile**

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion. I suppose I may get better support this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the open source drivers, the fact that power management (`dpm`) is enabled should be reflected by the existence of a file named

```
/sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_state
```

(or the same with `card0` or other number, whichever is your AMD card). I have more links and insights in [my answer about AMD hybrid system overheating](https://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395).