# how to disable discrete graphic in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, graphics

I want know how to disable discrete graphic in Ubuntu 14.04 ,my computer's gaphic cards are Intel and ATI 5650. I only want to use the Integrated card because the temperature of computer can stay low.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395 if you do not want to install the proprietary drivers (or if they do not work).

Answer (score 1):

Install the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

then open the amd catalyst control center and disable the 5650.

TLP helps laptop reduce the ammount of power consumed in a much more efficient way than any other:

First: Uninstall laptop mode tools

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

Then install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

Finally start it:

```
sudo tlp start
```

Comment: Brask, +1 but would be nice if you add some link on what to do if the proprietary drivers fail to work --- it happens all too often, and it is not clear how to go back.

Comment: it is also not work on my computer, when I install fglrx ,Ubuntu can't start. the screen display "run in low-graphic mode", I can not fix this problem, so I come back to 13.10 @Brask