# Computer overheats and shuts down kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, steam, overheating

My dad has been recomending me to get linux for a long time. Recently I got a driver error on Windows 8, it escalated and now Windows will not boot up anymore. My dad told me to get Kubuntu so atleast I didn't have a dead computer. Ever since I got it, my computer has gotten VERY hot. When I play games from Steam like Garry's Mod, Team Fortress 2, etc. my computer will get very hot (this has never happened before) and it will get so hot it will shut off, crash, "blow a fuse," whatever you want to call it. Just on the Internet it's hot.

I don't know what to do anymore.

It is not the battery being in my laptop when it is plugged in.

If anyone knows please help me out thanks! Ask Questions if you have any.

P.S. I have Kubuntu 14.04 and have gotten the most recent software update as of 6/17/14

Comment: Please add data about your computer; model, graphic card, graphic driver. If it's a AMD-based computer using the opensource driver, check http://askubuntu.com/questions/207733/why-does-my-laptop-with-amd-radeon-hd-76xx-graphics-get-overheated-when-using-ub

Comment: It's a fan management problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on my laptop HP Compaq nx8220 with Kernel 3.13.0-24 to 3.13.0-30 (in Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint 17). This laptop ran Ubuntu and now Mint since 8 years without overheating problems.
Try to boot from an older Live-DVD or USB stick with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS or Linux Mint 13. If this will fix your CPU fan then a bug in kernel 3.13.x might cause the problem.

I was able to fix it today with a pre-release of kernel 3.13.0-32 from https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

**Careful users should wait a few days to get this fixed kernel as a normal update!**

From what I have read the problem was a kernel patch called "ACPI / AC: convert ACPI ac driver to platform bus" which has now been reverted in kernel 3.13.0-31 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

To talk for sure whether it is hardware or software issue you should have a bit more things checked. The pure experiment would be ideally to resurrect your Windows and check whether it overheats or doesn't.

As you said you got the Windows issue with driver, it stopped working/booting, and then you ran Ubuntu, well, it doesn't exclude that your machine had been already overheating somehow by that time. Anyway, to exclude potential fault of Ubuntu and its particular kernel you should run something else on your laptop. You can try Live CD. In there you can select "Try", not "Install". Or revive your Windows again to compare. You will need to repair a boot however if you do this.

To dig deeper into diagnosing of this issue, and namely, to define whether it is software or hardware you can install some OS( say previous Ubuntu version, or Windows) on the new partition of your local drive, or to external drive or on USB flash.

Moreover, you are recommended to install CPU temperature monitor, for example`psensor`
(it shows hardware sensors and fan speeds)

`sudo apt-get install psensor`

to check your CPU temperature. Other wise you will need to go to BIOS "health" monitor to see it every time the system crashes when it is hot. You need the value to understand what happens.

You will probably find that your CPU overheats and goes up to 100C+. If it happens on all OS/kernel's combinations, this means it is a hardware issue. This may involve a number of things, from fan getting bad, dust, dirt and even to to the CPU degrading.

Anyway you will probably find usefull `indicator-cpufreq` program, which allows you to scale CPU frequency - to set it down (list is offered in there).

`sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq`

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try back porting to an older kernel. That seems to be a known bug in the more recent versions Kubuntu.

Comment: This is really not useful without references. Please add a link to the bug at least.