# My laptop is seriously overheating

Tags: drivers, ati, cpu, overheating, fan

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 7 on my laptop about an hour ago, and within two minutes of running Ubuntu (both during the Live CD and post-install), my CPU temperatures reach 100°C. In Windows 7, I limited the processor state to 72% to avoid overheating, but it never got this bad, even with it at 100%. I'm using an HPG62-340US, with an ATI Mobility Radeon 4200 graphics card. This isn't the first time I've tried installing Ubuntu on this laptop, and I've had the same problem every time, but no answer I find works for me; it's always "clean your fan" or "apply new thermal paste" but seeing as how Windows doesn't give me third degree burns then I think that there is a solution that will work for Ubuntu that doesn't require me ripping my computer apart.

Comment: There might be something about your setup that is worsening your particular situation, since I don't get those temperatures, but basically same here; I've never heard the fan of the laptop in Windows 8, nor in Debian Jessie, nor in Trusty, but it's spinning *loudly* in Vivid, so it must be something about Vivid; try running `top` and see if some process is eating the cpu %

Comment: Different card, but maybe can help: http://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395

Comment: I have the same problem with HP laptop. I think its HP that has issues not windows or Ubuntu. I now use cooling pad which helps somewhat

Answer (score 0):

Wow!!*That must be really 'hot'!* Sometimes, it could be a process that is using quite a lot of CPU. But, because the fan needs to cool the computer, you could probably hear your fan right? If you just can get to install Ubuntu, it might stop doing that.

## But you must be thinking, there has to be something increasing temperature! And it might do it all the time!

Well, options have been thought of for you......

1. Either get a Linux distribution that won't need so much CPU.http://www.howtogeek.com/172987/revive-your-old-pc-the-3-best-linux-systems-for-old-computers/
2. If you do get to the end of installation. Get this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/jupiter-applet-finally-available-for.html

3.If you can, you can also get the system monitor (if you install Ubuntu)

4. Dun Dun Dunn...never boot Linux again and go back to windows :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my HP Pavilion g6-2248ca notebook.The overheating is basically due to the linux kernal in Ubuntu 15.04 is not able to adopt the hybrid graphics in HP PCs properly(I think this is probably a bug).Furthermore I resolved the issue by switching to Ubuntu 14.04.You should try to switch Ubuntu 14.04.If switching does not help just go back to windows where HP Coolsensors would take care this problem.