# Reuced battery backup and overheating!

Tags: 14.04, overheating

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my laptop. Surprisingly battery backup has reduced to one third. Moreover it feels like my laptop is burning inside. Its bottom surface is way too hot than it used to be when I had Windows OS.

Can I fix it or I have to get back on to Windows OS (regretting my decision of switching to Ubuntu)

**System Specs:**
DELL latitude E5440
Intel i5-4200 CPU - 4GB RAM
no additional graphic cards (like AMD or NVIDIA)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my laptop with AMD Radeon HD 76xx graphics get overheated when using Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207733/why-does-my-laptop-with-amd-radeon-hd-76xx-graphics-get-overheated-when-using-ub)

Comment: There are plenty of questions on this website about overheating. If you cannot find your answer in those, specify your system spec so one can give relevant suggestion

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha its DELL latitude E5440. Intel i5-4200 CPU 500 GB HDD and 4GB RAM. with no additional graphic cards(like AMD or NVIDIA).

Comment: Try to use powertop to see what are the power settings.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop-mode-tools or tlp is needed to be installed to optimise your laptop battery. Please note it should be either of the two. Hope it helps.

Linux usually fail to match Windows battery management due to lack of proprietary driver support, we have to rely on open source drivers in many cases.