# Wacom issues with the Fujitsu T4220 & T4210 Tablet PC

Tags: 14.04, suspend, hibernate, tablet, wacom

Could someone take a look at the wacom issues? aparently I am not the only one having these issues but on my Fujitsu T4220 & T4210 tablet PCs I can't unplug the wacom to reset it. Everything works great if not a bit slow; but when it comes back on from suspend the OS says there is no tablet device, I have to reboot for it to see the wacom tablet again. It is slightly annoying and has caused me to reconsider going back to ubuntu 12.04 (wacom works perfect on there) or switching to another distro after using ubuntu for several years now.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo rmmod wacom; sudo modproble wacom` after resume? If yes you can look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/511068/wacom-tablet-removed-after-sleep-mode  (BTW, please try to describe the problem in more detail, removing the personal comments and rants... they do not help).

Comment: there is no more details, it is simply not there after coming back from suspend, no error messages or nothing and yes that works, read your link and all fixed now thanks. sorry for the rant...at the time of ranting it never seems like a rant.

Comment: OK if it's fixed I'll mark this as duplicate. Please upvote the other answer when you can.